Bayesian network: how to speed up inference(s)?
I'm experimenting with open-source python libraries that can handle Bayesian networks easily. However the inference is slower compared to the commercial solution (SMILE). One slower inference would not really be a problem, but for one use-case we are calculating lots of inferences and my question is how could we speed this up, combining some calculations or similar. The most time-consuming calculation is this:

do initial inference for all nodes/variables with 0 evidence (I use
node and variable interchangeably)
iterate over ~40-50-60% of our nodes (let's call them "observables";
size depends on the given network)

for every observable node set one of the states as evidence (do it
for all possible states, which number can usually be around 2-3-4)
calculate inference for the other 40-50-60% of nodes
calculate a value for the observable node which shows how much
effect/impact changing its state has on the rest of the variables
(~comparing original inference with 0 evidence to the just now
calculated probabilities - this is not a complicated calculation)



I'm not sure if there is an existing terminology for this kind of calculation, but basically what we are calculating is the impact of some variables (1 by 1) on the probabilities of others. I think this could be done in a smarter way, but don't know how.
I'd appreciate any ideas!
Meanwhile I'm trying to solve the speed issue with GPU usage and parallelization but it would be much better to use a smarter algorithm and/or somehow speed up single inference.
Example network consists of 188 nodes and 289 edges.
(Btw, I've tried pgmpy and pomegranate and contacted the authors regarding single inference speed. Also tried pymc but couldn't make it work yet.)
